# I have a problem implementing the typescript generic function, even though individual function resolves properly

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript problem that I'm trying to solve

```
type BasicParam = {
  basic: string
}

type ComplexParam = {
  complex: {
    name: string
    type: string
    date: {
      timestamp: string,
      unix: number
    }
  }
}

/** 
 * I tried to create a generic function, 
 * by structures that can conditionally return their appropriate type
 * by the type of the param that is passed in GenericHelper function
 */
function GenericHelper<T extends 'basic' | 'complex'>(t: T): {
  id: number;
  obj: T extends 'basic' ? BasicParam : T extends 'complex' ? ComplexParam : never
} {
  if (t === 'complex') {
    return {
      id: 0,
      obj: {
        complex: {
          name: "",
          type: "",
          date: {
            timestamp: "",
            unix: 0
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  throw new Error();
}
```

The error I'm facing is

```
(property) obj: RequiredStructure<T>

Type '{ basic: string; }' is not assignable to type 'RequiredStructure<T>'.(2322)

input.tsx(33, 3): The expected type comes from property 'obj' which is declared here on type 'RootObject<T>'
```

Individual Specified types work as expected, so I guess my condition types are working properly.

What Am I doing wrong, Thanks In Advance

Comment: Thanks, Matt Pocock for a simplified version of the function

Comment: You're not really doing anything "wrong", but the compiler can't verify that any value is assignable to a generic conditional type.  See [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and the linked question for more information.  If I were you I'd just [use an assertion](https://tsplay.dev/wRGK1N) and move on.